# Hibernate subquery apply DetachedCriteria to ManyToMany join table

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery, detachedcriteria

I'm trying to create a subquery that will take a DetachedCriteria that selects from the join table where there are entries for an entity; essentially I want to see if an entity has any associations via the join table.

Depending on a passed boolean I'll add a `exists` or `notExists` subquery to the criteria.

Basically I want to take the subquery in this sql:

```
select * from A as leftEntity where not exists (select * from A_B where A = leftEntity.id);`
```

and create a detached criteria. I can't figure out the correct entity to pass to create the detached criteria - I'm trying to do something on the join table, not entity A or B. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I gave up trying to use DetachedCriteria and just used an sqlRestriction on the criteria;

`criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("exists (select a from a_b where a = {alias}.id)"));`

Comment: I like your approach :-)